# Looking for demos, sample code and tutorial about JSON.NET

Tags: json.net

I am looking for demos, sample code and tutorial about JSON.NET.
I would prefer demonstrations ready to use.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Serialize or deserialize json?  Sample json would be helpful.

Comment: I agree!  Love what I *think* JSON.NET can do, but MAN is that documentation lacking!  It's great if you already know how to use it for a quick reference, but that's it!  For instance, I'm just looking for a way that I can customize the way a particular .NET class (de)serializes, and I know it has something to do with the converters and contracts, but damn if I can't find even ONE example of this (except in pieces... nothing altogether) so I'm stuck scratching my head, wasting hours on something that should take minutes at best. (Our class has 2 properties that JSON.NET's default barfs on.)

Comment: @MarqueIV - please post a sample of the JSON that you want to deserialize (or class that you would like to serialize) and I may be able to help.

Comment: Just look for questions posted by me.  In the past few days I've made several.