# JSON.NET Tutorial

Tags: .net, xcode, json, json.net

Can anyone help me in finding some code examples or tutorials to understand how to use JSON.NET features.
The documentation seems to be a litle confusing and difficult for me to undersatand.
I am new in field of JSON and .NET
Thanks
Puneet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for demos, sample code and tutorial about JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796474/looking-for-demos-sample-code-and-tutorial-about-json-net)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check the examples given here:

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

If you are still confused then provide detail of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Start off with 
http://www.json.org/

Then check out 
http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

Using Json with .NET is really easy.